# How to count the number of array of object id's and increment

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ecmascript-6

probably an easy question but a bit stumped, given this JSON structure:

```
{
    "users": [{
        "action": "update",
        "payload": [{
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Albin Jaye"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "Dave Mustaine"
            }
        ]
    }],
```

I am testing a conditional for the `users` key, and then of course for creating a new entry in another file for `payload` I need to increment the id counter So, I have been trying this, but not working:

```
if(actionDetail.action === 'create') {
    console.log('This is a CREATE entry');
    var size = Object.keys(actionDetail.payload[0]).length;
    console.log(size);
}
```

of course this doesn't work, I don't need the number of keys, I just simply need to know how to count the total numbers of objects in the `payload` array of objects (2 total) not sure how to do this?  I am guessing a nifty use of .reduce() could do it, or similar? i.e. set a const to the reduce() and then add +1 so I have 3 in the variable for new record to be added!

Comment: You would want `actionDetail.payload.length` to get the number of objects in the `payload` array.

Comment: Sweet!  thanks a ton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `array.length` to get the total length of an array.

In your question, you just need to change one simple part to get the length of payload array.

```
  var size = actionDetail.payload.length;
```

You can also read about `array.length` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length), let me know if you have doubts.